# What form of government would there be in space colonies?

Tags: colonization, law

I'm curious about the initiatives out there to regulate the space colonization, once it becomes affordable for most countries.

Would the government in the colonies be like some sort of federation with representatives of countries of the Earth, for instance?

Could the democracy be superseded by a benevolent dictatorship of such federation?

Comment: All I know is that if it were the US form of government with its ability to make decisions, in that hostile environment they'd all be dead within six months.

Comment: Interesting question. We don't really have much to work on short of theories tho, and even those mostly presented in fiction and/or philosophy works. I'm no expert but reading through a lot of books that also dived into this (brave authors!!), I think it would start as exterritorial representative democracy or continuum of whatever it started from and would eventually settle in some form of [bioregional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioregional_democracy) [industrial democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_democracy). If it had the chance to evolve that far, like Mark Adler said.

Comment: The big question here is how far-off the colony would be. I.e. if we establish a colony on Tau Ceti, but communication takes years, and travel between the two takes centuries, there isn't much government possible, let alone needed.

Comment: Hello rraallvv. While this version of the question is too much on the speculative side to work with the Q&A format of Stack Exchange, a version that would focus on current regulations and initiatives would be on topic on our sister site [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com/). Before you post there, however, I'd invite you to take at least a quick look at [UNOOSA's](http://www.unoosa.org/) site, and more specifically at the [Outer Space Treaty](http://www.unoosa.org/oosa/SpaceLaw/outerspt.html).

Comment: (specific) Questions on the political aspects of bioregionalism (see @TildalWave's comment) would also be welcomed on Politics, if you are interested in further exploring the concept.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I'll try to post a more comprehensive question, may be in Politics SE.